# How to cache credentials for VS online in posh-git?

Tags: azure-devops, posh-git

I use Visual Studio online with git and PowerShell (posh-git). I setup alternate credential in my VS profile so I have username/password. Whenever I issue `git pull` in posh-git I have to enter my credentials - it is quite annoying. Can I cache it somehow at least while the PowerShell is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [popular posh-git credentials search results](https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=posh-git%20user%20email&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=qg-AVZi8PIu_-Qa_yoGIAg#channel=fs&q=posh-git%20credentials) you need a small helper app called [git-credential-winstore](http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex that is perfect for your use case.

References

- [Setting up the Perfect Git Command Line Environment on Windows](http://www.woodwardweb.com/git/setting_up_the.html)
- [Installing Posh-Git](http://alexsolution.com/blog/?p=27)

Comment: outdated, see [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34757130/11635) - @eXavier can this be deleted and/or unaccepted please?

Answer (score 4):

Sascha Gottfried answer is right but it is a little out of date now, you now need to install Git Credential Manager for Windows

https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/

Download Link: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/latest

Comment: I found it useful to install git 2.9 myself via `get-packageprovider -name chocolatey; install-package git` (i.e. install 2.9 or newer git via chocolatey, see www.hanselman.com/blog/AptGetForWindowsOneGetAndChocolateyOnWindows10.aspx) rather than letting the GCM install it (`install-package githubforwindows` had left me with git 2.8)